# Move all objects from a subview to its superview in interface builder

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I have a ViewController.xib file. This has a main view. I added a subview to that and added all of my objects there. I now no longer want that subview and I want to move all of the objects to the superview. Image below:

[image]

When I try to move all of the objects to the superview by dragging them up the formatting gets all messed up (they all get centered on the superview). It is very hard to get them reformatted. Is there an easy way to get rid of the superview and put the subview in its place?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply drag the subview out of the super view and add the main view reference to the subview i:e, connect the super view outlet to the subview now the super view remains just  empty view which has no connections to controller .You can delete it also . but make sure u made subview as ur main view outlet . hope u got me.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out. Move the subview on top of the superview, and add the referencing outlet view.